# C++ Difference between new char[size] and new char[size]()

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

tldr; What is the difference between allocating memory for a primitive array with the parenthesis vs without them? e.g.

```
char * text = new char[size];
```

vs.

```
char * text = new char[size]();
```

Full Story:

I came across a strange issue today with some code I was writing. I created a class that contained a cstring member variable, text.

```
Class SomeClass
{
   private:
      char * text;
      ...
}
```

The constructor of said class would initialize text with dynamically allocated memory like so

```
text = new char[size];
```

When run, my program would prompt the user for input, store the input in the cstring, and display it back to the user. The problem was, when I used cout to display the cstring back to the user, garbage would appear on the end of the string. When I would step through the program with a debugger, the bug vanished, and the cstring would print normally. The problem only appeared when running the program, and never when stepping through with a debugger.

After making sure my cstring had the appropriate null terminating character, adequate memory was being allocated for the user input, array bounds were checked, and many other things, I finally fixed the issue by adding parenthesis after the square brackets when I allocated memory for the cstring like so

```
text = new char[size]();
```

Why did this fix my problem?  What is the difference between allocating memory for a primitive array with the parenthesis vs without them?

Comment: `new char[size]()` would zero-initialize the array. `new char[size]` would leave it uninitialized, containing random garbage.

Comment: The parentheses version initializes the chars to `0`

Comment: What fantastically quick responses! Thanks to both of you! That makes total sense. I knew it had to do with something like that.

Comment: *"After making sure my cstring had the appropriate null terminating character"* I suspect that you have not, in fact, done that. Somewhere, somehow, you end up with a string that is not nul-terminated. Zeroing out the whole buffer just has the side effect of nul-terminating whichever string is later placed into that buffer.

Comment: generally you should have `str = new char[size + 1]; str[size] = '\0';`

Comment: @BenVoigt generally you should use `string` or `vector` :P

Comment: @M.M: Or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, which works in conjunction with `new[]` in C++11 (and then C++14 adds `make_unique`)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Igor Tandetnik and M.M. in the comments. The parentheses initialize the chars in the array to 0 instead of garbage. This means that cout will stop printing chars at the first 0 it encounters instead of printing all the garbage contained in the string.

Comment: If all you need is to zero-terminate an empty string, then setting just `text[0]` to zero would have been sufficient. Zeroing the entire buffer from the beginning to the end just for that purpose alone could be wasteful. Depends on several factors, of course.